# How can I securely erase a variable in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I will be using data from a keychain in various cryptographic operations, and want to ensure that I remove any in-memory trace once complete.

I want to prevent any memory dump, or other low level investigation that would expose the secret (or a derivative of it)

This question has a good description of what I'm looking for, however I'm looking for a   Objective C approach.

[Would it be good secure programming practice to overwrite a “sensitive” variable before deleting it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74280/396)

Comment: What class is the data that you're dealing with?

Comment: @EliSadoff I will ultimately be using Xamarin, which uses Obj C under the covers.  Getting an Obj C understanding would help me deduce the Xamarin approach

Comment: Even if you clear the variable in memory, is not that difficult to read what it's inside a keychain using a jailbroken device.

Comment: @andrea I intend to protect the keychain with a key in the secure element  related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/141743/396